# Solving $T(n) = 2^n T(n-1) + 2^n$

Tags: recurrence-relations

Is there an exact (and if not, an asymptotic) solution to the following recurrence relation?
$$
T(n) = 2^n T(n-1) + 2^n, \text{for } n > 0
$$

If yes, I'd also like to know whether this relation is an instance of a more general class of relations for which you can apply the same technique for solving it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sketch:

- Let $u_n$ denote the value of $T(n)$ obtained if $T(0)=0$. Prove by induction $T(n)=2^{n(n+1)/2}T(0)+u_n$.
- Define $v_n:=u_n/2^{n(n+1)/2}$ so $T(n)=2^{n(n+1)/2}(T(0)+v_n)$. Prove by induction $v_n=v_{n-1}+2^{-n(n-1)/2}$.
- Since $v_0=0$, $T(n)=2^{n(n+1)/2}(T(0)+\sum_{k=1}^n2^{-k(k-1)/2})$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the definition of $u_n$: what is meant by "the value of $T(n)$ obtained if $T(0) = 0$"?

Comment: @MoB. You defined a family of sequences parameterized by $T(0)$, so I expressed each such sequence in terms of the one with $T(0)=0$.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks.